# adding listview items to combox: visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to add all items from listview1 to combobox1
i tryed

```
For Each item In listview.Items
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
```

but all the combobox1 items have 'ListViewItem: {foo}' around the items from listbox (foo)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Text() property of the ListViewItem:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(item.Text)
```